# Design architecture to contact 3rd party Web Service

Tags: web-services, architecture

Actually the code is structured as in the first design. But I think it's not very readable..

- The **namespaces name** are saying nothing of the **responsability** of each class
- Is it really **useful to split between DAO and BLO** layer a so small architecture? There is almost no logic..
- The logic / responsability of the BLO is not identifiable by the names of class / methods / namespace
- What is UserType? *The namespace is not grouping it with any other class*..
- **Config** class is a good name for me since it identifies a functionality. But It'**s the only class with a precise purpose specified by its name.**
- Get3rdPartyUrl and logging in (to that url) **could all be put together** in a same class, while InitializeConfigValue and ParseErrorMessage could be put into some other Help class.

**Contacting a 3rdParty WS is reusable. Everything should inherit from just one interface also defining logging.**

The WS which I contact will make a callback to my infrastructure. I could I recognize / trace the session between this two calls? From my infrastructure and back to my infrastructure?

I wait your comment and proposal!

[image]

**EDIT**

**This is the result after the first refactoring. What do you think about?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not split beetwen DAO and BLO levels in small projects. I use [QueryObject pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html) and put all my queries into this objects. You can put simple logic (validation f.e.) into this queries.

> The WS which I contact will make a callback to my infrastructure. I could I recognize / >trace the session between this two calls? From my infrastructure and back to my >infrastructure?

You can use [WS-Addressing](http://www.w3.org/Submission/ws-addressing/). WS-Addressing headers has fields `wsa:MessageID` and `wsa:RelatesTo` for message correlations (mean this as MessageId and CorrelationId) and `wsa:ReplyTo/wsa:Address` for callback server address.

For example Oracle SOA Suite has strong WS-Addressing support out-of-the-box.

Comment: WS-Addressing is easily supported by .net / WCF?

Comment: I do not work with .net/WCF but .NET/WCF supports WS-Addressing: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/wcf-ws-addressing-march-2004